# Angularjs / Ui-router : how to make ng-repeat list items link to a .html page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building my first angularjs app, for my routing i use ui-router wich works great!

I want to achieve the following: in my app the user can search for a name/place etc. in a input field i got this working just fine. When the user finds what he is looking for they need to be able to click on the information and go to the page it belongs to.

So for example i search for "MacDonalds" i get to see the following "logo, name, adres, place, website" when i click this i will go to a page in my app with more information about MacDonalds.

I tried to do this as shown below.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'view/home.html'

  })
  .state('restaurants', {
    url: '/restaurants',
    templateUrl: 'view/restaurants.html'

  })
  .state('contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    templateUrl: 'view/contact.html'
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';

 }]);

 function RestaurantCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.restaurantlist = [
{
  name: 'A1-plaza',
  adres: 'Ruimtevaart 8',
  place: '3824 MX Amersfoort',
  tel: '033 468 1988',
  website: 'www.a1-plaza.nl',
  logo: 'img/a1-plaza.png',
  id: 'a1plaza'

},
{
  name: 'De Faam',
  adres: 'Hamseweg 5',
  place: '3828 AA Hoogland',
  tel: '033 480 1213',
  website: 'www.defaam.nl',
  logo: 'img/defaam.png',
  id: 'defaam'
}

];
};

app.controller('RestaurantCtrl', RestaurantCtrl);
```

**home.html**

```
<section class="row">
<article class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="RestaurantCtrl">
<p>je kan momenteel zoeken op a1-plaza en de faam zowel naam als plaats en adres gegevens (dit blijft hier niet staan nienke ;)</p>
    <form role="form"> 
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input ng-model="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoek uw locatie, restaurant" />
            <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-show="search" ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantlist | filter:search">
            <td>
                <a style="display: block;" ui-sref="restaurant.detail">
                    <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{restaurant.logo}}">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a style="display: block;" ui-sref="restaurant.detail">
                    {{restaurant.name}}<br> {{restaurant.adres}}<br>
                    {{restaurant.place}}<br> {{restaurant.tel}}<br>
                    {{restaurant.website}}
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</article>
```

I've been trying to find a solution for a good 4 hours and can't figure out what is the best way to do this / how to do this. if you know a good solution please let me know, with if possible an example and some explanation

The app is online at [check the app here](http://www.creativepixels.nl/newsite)

- Resize your browser for a better picture

**EDIT:**

With the help of @thedoctor i now inserted his solution, and changed my html "ng-href" to ui-sref="restaurant.detail". I also added an ID to the restaurants. So how do i make a propper restaurantService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to define another state which would show the view of an individual restaurant, it will be parameterized by the restaurant id (or something similar).

I am assuming that you have a service "restaurantService" which acts as the interface to the server, alternatively you can use $http or $resource directly.

```
.state('restaurant.detail', {
        url: '/restaurants/:id',
        templateUrl: 'view/restaurant.html',
        controller: function($scope, restaurant){
          $scope.restaurant = restaurant.data;
        },
        resolve: {
            restaurant: function (restaurantService, $stateParams) {
                return restaurantService.get({id: $stateParams.id});  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a service as i mentioned i'm new to angularjs. Could you help me out just a little more i see the logic in using another state for the details but i don't know how to connect the details state with my ng-href in home.html

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggestion i think i'm all set now, just cant figure out how to make a service for this. thanks in advanced

Comment: AngularJs best practice is to break your code into controllers, services, directives and filters, but you don't have to. You can access your server side REST API like '/restaurants/:id', using $resource to fetch the data using a call such as var restaurantService = $resource.get('/restaurants/:id', {id: '@id'}); restaurantService.get({id: '123'}, function (response) { ... handle response here ... }); see the AngularJS docs for $resource for more info.

Comment: well unfortunately im still not able to figure it out, guess its a bit to hardcore for me :( But thanks for the help anyway!